# Can we target .Net Standard 2.0 projects with Visual Studio 2017 Express?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-express, .net-standard-2.0

I just installed Visual Studio 2017 Express for Windows Desktop (version 15.5.4), and I am trying to open a C# project that targets the framework .Net Standard 2.0.

But it doesn't work, it tells me that the project needs a migration. I reload the project and VS performs this "one way upgrade", but when trying to compile afterwards, I get this error:
`The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Standard 2.0. Either target .NET Standard 1.6 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Standard 2.0`.

What bothers me is that the most recent version of the SDK is already installed, running the command `dotnet --info` tells me that the current version for the .Net Core is 2.0.5.

Also, I tried installing Visual Studio Community 2017 (instead of Express), and everything worked just fine, the .Net Standard 2.0 framework was detected.
But I can't use VS Community because of its licence.

So in the end my question is, is it possible to "use" the .Net Standard 2.0 framework with VS 2017 Express ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: is your install all up to date?

Comment: Yes, I'm using VS 2017 Express 15.5.4.

Comment: did you install .net core support?

Comment: oh windows desktop might not work - try using the web version

Comment: I can only find a link to download the windows desktop version for VS Express [https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-express/?rr=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.ca%2F](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-express/?rr=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.ca%2F)

Comment: looks like it doesn't support web. try using vs code or something else

Comment: Not sure I understand, I can build and run my project using Visual Studio Code ?

Comment: yea. its a free version that works well w/ .net core

Comment: I will check that out. But in the meantime, is it 100% sure that I cannot open/run projects targeting .Net Standard 2.0 with VS 2017 Express ?

Comment: i'm pretty sure. .net core really targets for web, not desktop